# How to execute more than one Future and wait for it done before for loop in java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future, callable

hi how do i execute 3 callable function so i don't have to wait when do another process and in some point i will have to wait them for complete before i can move to my next line of my code properly? here is what i do :

i have a function that return value as Callable :

```
public <T> Callable<List<T>> getDataFromOtherAPI(List<Long> ids, String url, Class<T> tClass){
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

    //NOTE init mapper
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); 
    //NOTE end of init mapper

    CollectionType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, tClass);

    List<T> object = webClient.post()
        .uri(url).body(Mono.just(ids), Object.class)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, res -> res.bodyToMono(ExceptionResponse.class)
                .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new ResourceNotFound("Something Happened")))
                .flatMap(errorBody -> Mono.error(new ResourceNotFound(errorBody.getMessage())))
        )
        .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>() {})
        .block();
    
    List<T> mappedClass = mapper.convertValue(object, listType);

    if(mappedClass.size() == 0) {
        throw new ResourceNotFound("Data in Url " + url + " not found");
    }

    return () -> mappedClass;
}
```

this is how i declare my execs :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("executor")
private AsyncTaskExecutor execs;
```

then here is how i try to call from another api in my function :

```
Future<List<PartnerDto>> initPartners = execs.submit(getDataFromOtherAPI(
            transDeliveryPlanningDtSoDtoPartnerIds, b2b.getPartnerSpecificId(), PartnerDto.class));
    
Future<List<PartnerShipmentDto>> initPartnerShipments = execs.submit(getDataFromOtherAPI(
            transDeliveryPlanningDtSoDtoPartnerShipmentIds, b2b.getPartnerShipmentSpecificId(), PartnerShipmentDto.class));
    
Future<List<ProductResponseDto>> initProduct = execs.submit(getDataFromOtherAPI(
            transDeliveryPlanningDtSoDetailDto, b2b.getProductSpecificId(), ProductResponseDto.class));
    
    //another much process
    
    //end of another much process
    
    //i have to hold over here before i continue into my next process to do some for loop :
    
    for(TransDeliveryPlanningDtSoDto e : d.getTransDeliveryPlanningDtSoDto()) {
                        
         PartnerDto latestPartner = new PartnerDto();
         PartnerShipmentDto latestPartnerShipment = new PartnerShipmentDto();
         TransSalesOrder latestSalesOrder = new TransSalesOrder();
        
         latestProduct = initProduct.stream().filter(so -> productId.equals(so.getId())).findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFound("Product " + so.getIs() + " Not Found"));
         latestPartner = initPartners.stream().filter(partner -> partnerId.equals(partner.getId())).findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFound("Partner " + partnerName + " Not Found"));
         latestPartnerShipment = initPartnerShipments.stream().filter(partnerShipment -> partnerShipmentId.equals(partnerShipment.getId())).findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFound("PartnerShipment Not Found"));
        
        }
```

i have to add something to hold/wait for the async process done right? how do i do this?

Comment: Never call `block()` - simply forward the `Mono` to the Spring to platform. Currently you’re returning a callable but you’re doing all the work creating it and the deferred execution itself is a no op. Because of this, your attempt to parallelise will do nothing.

Comment: can u give me the example? i use WebClient because i read RestTemplate is going to deprecated in near future, that's why i decided to do this

Comment: this would be rather easier to answer if you would simplify it, it's a lot of code that only you know about. As simpler question would draw a lot more attention, imo.